# Why I’m getting an “Operator ‘==’ cannot be applied to operands of type ‘string’ in this DHTMLX Scheduler tutorial?

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-3

I couldn’t find any post of similar problem so I thought I would ask on this forum.  I’m folling a tutorial on building a DGTMLS Scheduler  found here:  http://blog.scheduler-net.com/post/5-Steps-to-a-Simple-Scheduler-in-ASPNET-MVC3MVC4.aspx.

Everything was going fine until I got to a line that tries to do a query based on Source Id.  Here’s the line

changedEvent = data.Events.SingleOrDefault(ev=>ev.id==action.SourceId);

Here I get the error message Operator ‘==’ cannot be applied to operands of type ‘string’ and ‘long’.

The code block is posted below.  Can someone please tell me why I’m getting an “Operator ‘==’ cannot be applied to operands of type ‘string’?

```
public ContentResult Save(int? id, FormCollection actionValues)
    {
        var action = new DataAction(actionValues);
        var changedEvent = (Event)DHXEventsHelper.Bind(typeof(Event), actionValues);
        var data = new SampleDataContext();



        try
        {
           // var changedEvent = (CalendarEvent)DHXEventsHelper.Bind(typeof(CalendarEvent), actionValues);



            switch (action.Type)
            {
                case DataActionTypes.Insert://define here your Insert logic
                    data.Events.InsertOnSubmit(changedEvent);




                    break;
                case DataActionTypes.Delete://define here your Delete logic
                    changedEvent = data.Events.SingleOrDefault(ev=>ev.id==action.SourceId);
                    break;
                default:// "update"                          
                    //do update
                    break;
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            action.Type = DataActionTypes.Error;
        }
        return (ContentResult)new AjaxSaveResponse(action);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Because you are trying to compare `string` with a `long` directly. You can't do that in C#, either you need to parse `string` to `long`, or convert `long` to `string`. Then do the comparison like this:

```
var sourceId = action.SourceId.ToString();
data.Events.SingleOrDefault(ev => ev.id == sourceId);
```

In this case I'm assuming `ev.id` is `string` and `actions.SourceId` is `long`..

Answer (score 1):

Actually, `Operator ‘==’ cannot be applied to operands of type ‘string’ and ‘long’` is simply tells the problem. Between two different type, auto casting cannot be done. You should manually convert and then compare them.